# Jquery show different data-id per each li on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a menu to my website. My idea is on the left side of the web the menu will appear. The menu will have X `<li>` and with X icon per each `<li>`, when my mouse is over I want to appear X data-id per each `<li>` + the icon.

For example:

```
<ul><li data-id="My Profile">ICON</li></ul>
```

On mouse over:

```
<ul><li>ICON + My Profile</li></ul>
```

Here I have an example that doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/pqa84nec/1/

Here's the JS I'm trying to use:

```js
$("#menu").each(function() {
 $(this).find('li').each(function(){
 var oldData = $(this).html();
 var data = $(this).attr("data-id");
 var that = this;
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
            $(that).html(oldData+data);
   }, 100);
        });
        $(this).mouseout(function () {
             $(this).html(oldData);
        });
 });
    });
```

Can you give me some help?

P.D.

As I can see, this code IS bugged:

[image: Bugged if you pass your mouse too fast]

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to use jQuery, you should load it first :) http://jsfiddle.net/pqa84nec/1/

Comment: Do you want this to be done using jQuery, or would a CSS solution work for you?

Comment: It doesn't matter haha I want to make this work! @UnexpectedPairofColons

Comment: Looks like it semi works when jQuery is loaded per GCyrillus.

However, note that there is a "bug" of sorts. If you quickly move your moouse over the `li` elements, it populates the boxes with the `data-id` text.

This is because it fired the `mouseout` function (where it resets the text) before it fired the `setTimeout` function where it populates the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#menu ul li").each(function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    var icon = _this.html()
    $(this).hover(function(e) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        _this.html(icon + _this.data('id'));
      }, 200);
    }, function(e) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        _this.html(icon);
      }, 200);
    })
  });
});
```

CSS Addition:

```
#menu>ul>a {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mh4hcuw4/

Comment: Still bugged, if you hover your mouse too fast, text don't hide. @acupajoe

Comment: @seergiue sorry about that, try it now

Comment: @seergiue happy to help :D

Answer (score 1):

You have many errors in your script Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu a li").each(function() {

    var oldData = $(this).html();
    var data = $(this).attr("data-id");

    $(this).mouseover(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(oldData + data);
        $(this).html(oldData + data)
      }, 100);
    });
    $(this).mouseout(function() {
      console.log(oldData);
      $(this).html(oldData)
    });

  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a CSS solution, here's something based on what you had. This way you don't have to rely on JavaScript to run your menu. It's nothing fancy, and there's plenty you could do to make it nicer, but it should get you started. In the fiddle I loaded the Font Awesome library to use the icons.

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                <span>My Profile</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
                <span>Log Out</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
html,body {
    background-color: #263238;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}
li {
  position: relative;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu {
  background-color: #37474f;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#menu > ul > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #263238;
}
#menu > ul > li > a {
  color: #263238;
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 50px;
}
#menu > ul > li > a i {
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
}
#menu > ul > li > a span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  left: 50px;
  max-width: 130px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease .2s;
  visibility: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#menu > ul > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #fbd75b;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
}
#menu > ul > li > a:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

And a fiddle to view: [jsfiddle.net/LjLvwb8q/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/LjLvwb8q/3/)

Comment: that's interesting! Thanks :D